# Java: edit/remove a specific line (with streams) directly into the original file

Tags: java, file, parsing, stream

This is my scenario: I have a huge .txt file (~16GB) that contains some lines that have to be removed (that can easily be found with a .contains()).
Obviously the idea of loading the whole file on RAM and explore it with a Scanner, then saving the results in a new .txt file is unfeasible (since I have 16GB of RAM).
I also know that with the streams I'm able to read the file line by line, avoiding the memory leak. What I don't know (and haven't been able to find) is wether it is possible to edit that specific line and put it back in its place into the file.
Otherwise, is it possible to just rewrite a new .txt file with just the "correct" lines in a similar way to the one that allows me to read line by line, so without loading the whole file in memory, since before or after it will become as huge as the original one?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a Stream Reader that will be reading your file line by line, and a Stream writer that will be outputting to the new file. If the reader doesn't find the line to edit the writer simply writes that line to the new file. If the reader spots the line it wishes to edit, create a method to manipulate the line and return it, then have the Writer write that manipulated line rather than the original one.

You won't be allowed to access the same file with a Streamreader and Streamwriter.